# Aave's V3 Supply APY

Tags: aave

I'm working on a lending protocol that partially based on Aave's V3 interest rate. I'm trying to understand the Supply APY. I only have one rate, don't have a stable and variable rate. I understand all of the variables outside of `SB_t` and `VB_t`.

Are those the amount of borrowers borrowing from that asset using that specific rate or the user's share of the amount that is borrowed from that asset?

[image]